# How you would say combination in Japanese?

Tags: word-choice, words, word-requests

Someone is trying to open a safe, a briefcase, or padlock, and that person says, "What's the **combination**?". Referring to sequence of numbers to open said lock. What's the Japanese equivalent for **combination** when used in this way?

EDIT: Someone put this as an answer earlier then deleted it:

> 組{くみ}み合{あ}わせが何ですか？

Was this wrong?

Comment: The deleted answer was a Google Translate answer and did not answer your question. 組み合わせ is "combination", however it means combination of puzzle pieces, the combination of food, etc. Not a padlock combination, but a general unity of items. English is the weird guy here with "combination" meaning multiple things :)

Comment: @user11589 I'm not so sure English is weird here.  "Combination" is just combining several things, putting several things together.  In the case of a padlock, you're putting the numbers together in order to unlock it.  Within the language itself, it makes perfect sense.  The problem is translating between these various internal perspectives.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[暗証番号]{あんしょうばんごう} is the appropriate word for those cases.
The same word is used for bank account PINs and ten-key door lock pass codes as well.

Comment: Please see edit above.

Answer (score 5):

How about [番号{ばんごう}](http://oshiete.goo.ne.jp/qa/3336119.html)? as in 暗証番号

Comment: Please see edit above.

Answer (score 1):

組み合わせ is combination/ grouping. 
Literal meaning:

- 組み　group
- 合わせ match/ matching

This is unfortunately not proper for padlock. It would give an entire whole different meaning if you are asking for matching padlock (in terms of shape, color, etc. to other padlock/ item that makes the original padlock looks better)